# EditTextPreferences, Show change setting confirmation dialog and response to user's choice

Tags: android, android-preferences

What i want to do is to ask the user when he is about to change the EditTextPreference and click ok, if a certain condition is true, ask him if he is sure he want to change the setting.

so if the condition is true i show a dialog ask him for yes or no and because of showing the dialog is async, i return false in the OnPreferenceChange callback to cancel the preference change.

if the user decided not to change the pref, i do nothing more. but if yes was clicked, i manually change the preference with and editor and commit the changes.

now after the user presses Yes (he wants to change the pref), if he clicks again on the EditTextPreference in the Preferences screen, he will se the old value in the EditText instead of the new value.

Only when he closes the Preferences screen and opens it again, he will see the new value.

So my question is, is there any method i can call in the "Yes" Dialog.OnClickListener() after the editor.commit() that will make the Preferences screen updated its views with new new value from the SharedPreferences?

or is there any other way to acheive what i want?

thanks

Code Example:

```
EditTextPreference etp;
etp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object newValue)
        {
            int a;
            int b;

            if(a < b) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Preferences.this);
                Dialog changeMaxCountConfirmationDialog = builder
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setTitle("Change Setting")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to change this setting")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new Dialog.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                //Because I return false anyway, I change the preference manually here
                                Editor editor = preference.getEditor();
                                editor.putString("key", newValue.toString());
                                editor.commit();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", null)
                        .create();
                changeMaxCountConfirmationDialog.show();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have simillar problem. I want to show the most recent value on the preference item and when I add the onPreferenceChange (when the user changed it, change the text indicating current preference) it keeps on not letting me save the new value. I even tried to save it manually and it was still not working. I still have to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

I found a two part solution to this. Part 1 involves adding an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to your PreferenceScreen.

**Part 1**

```
public class BaseSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        ...
    }


    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(YOUR_KEY)) {
            updateUI();
        }
    }
}
```

With this set up, you can now listen to preference changes on the `Preference` object instead of going through `SharedPreferences`.

**Part 2**

You can show the dialog inside the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` of the `Preference` object (as the OP has already done). If the user confirms their choice, you can use the preference's `setValue` function to set the new value resulting in `SharedPreferences` being updated and the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` being called. As stated in Part 1, `onSharedPreferenceChanged` can contain any UI updating logic (such as updating the preference's summary).

```
public class BaseSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        //Part 2
        final ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference(YOUR_KEY));
        listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object newValue) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(c)
                        .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to change this preference?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ((ListPreference)preference).setValue((String) newValue);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(YOUR_KEY)) {
            updateUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but might be helpful to others.

Instead of using an `Editor` simply use `EditTextPreference#setText()`.

I.e. replace your code

```
//Because I return false anyway, I change the preference manually here
Editor editor = preference.getEditor();
editor.putString("key", newValue.toString());
editor.commit();
```

with something like this:

```
//Because I return false anyway, I change the preference manually here
((EditTextPreference)preference).setText(newValue.toString());
```